# Does MySQL full search index use OR operation or AND operation on multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to perform this query

```
SELECT * FROM `jobslisting` 
WHERE MATCH (jobtitle,skills,jobdescription, experiencedescription)
AGAINST ('Testing')
```

And my requirement is that 'Testing' keyword should be tested against all columns and if found in even one column the record should be included in result. But this query is not working as I am expecting.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Here is a link with a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406940/match-against-with-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? the query you gave is already an "or" query

Comment: I mean If jobtitle matches 'Testing' but other attributes not that should be included. How can I do that?