# Why match against mysql innodb works only with one argument

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, match-against, fulltext-index

I have a problem with the `MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)` functions in MySQL.

I saw some examples of `MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)` but when I try them they are not working and shows an error:

```
#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list .
```

I have the latest version of XAMPP installed today and its details are:

```
database engin is : innodb (innodb now support fulltext)
php : 5.5.24
mysql :5.6.24
phpmyadmin :4.3.11
```

I have 4 columns with fulltext : (`subject`,`content`,...) and when I use this query it works:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `book` 
WHERE 
    MATCH(`subject`) 
    AGAINST('دارو' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

but when i use more than one argument for `MATCH()` it's not working and it shows an error #1191:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `book` 
WHERE 
    MATCH(`subject`,`content`) 
    AGAINST('دارو' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Yet I saw many example with two or three arguments for `MATCH()` as well as `AGAINST()`.

Help me, please. what can I do about this issue?

Comment: are you saying each column has its own fulltext index, or the fulltext index is across all four columns? try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406940/match-against-with-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: How is your `FULLTEXT` index defined? Can you show the output of `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: Please update your question with the output of:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE book`

Comment: I was in trouble. I alone had identified columns as Fulltext and i fix it . thanks guys